# Magento 2: Custom Payment Module with Credit Card Form

Tags: magento-2.1, payment-methods, payment-gateway

I created a custom **Payment Module** from http://cedcommerce.com/magento-2-module-creator/payment-module .
But this payment module has a simple **Place Order** button. I need a **Credit Card** form in payment module. Can someone help me? All the answers will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you found anything on this.?
I have same requirement. can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process Credit Card numbers, you have to comply to the [PCI-DSS (Payment Card Industry - Data Security Standard)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard). Even when you don't store the card numbers, you have to comply to [PCI-DSS level 4](https://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/the-pci-basicsquick-guide-what-do-small-merchants-need-to-do-to-achieve-pci-compliance/).

You probably want to use a payment service provider which will process the credit card transactions for you. Most payment service providers offer a Magento module for free.

Comment: All payment service modules are not available for Magento. Paytrace is one of the payment service provider, but it doesn't provide module for Magento. It process the payment in Magento using Api. That's why I want to make a custom payment module with credit card form in which I will implement paytrace Api.